# Combine results from two websites PHP/AJAX(?)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I want to get results from two websites and combine them together.
I'll show an example:
The two websites showing me the results ordered by price from low to high.
Example of results that may vary.

**website #1** *page **1***:

20$

30$

30$

30$

50$

End of page 1

---

**Website #2** *page **1***:

15.99$

15.99$

15.99$

19.99$

25.99$

End of page 1

---

the results combined will be:

15.99$

15.99$

15.99$

19.99$

20$ (result of website #1)

End of results page 1

---

As you can see some of the results won't show because i can't know what will be in the next page of website #2 in this example.
I thought to save this results and show them in its time later..

My questions:

1) Not sure if this is the correct way to do this

2) As i understand it's not possible to do it in php because of loading that will erase the saved results, so i probably need to do it in ajax, if so how?

- Note: can't use API for some reason.

Thanks!

Comment: You are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After [**doing more research**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/1011527) if you have a problem **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question. Be sure to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/1011527).

Comment: scrape all of both sites before sorting and display.

Comment: Hey Jay, Of course i'll write the code by myself, i want to be preper to understand how to do it and if it's possible.

Comment: @rtfm it's not possilbe unfortunately, there are too many pages and it will take too many resources to scrape all website for each user.

Comment: you dont do it "live" you do it once and store the results.

Comment: @rtfm so showing the user cached results? i will probably have to store few thousands search results, it is the best way? thanks!

Comment: The price is change often, so it can show wrong price..

Comment: every other price comparison site does this, they have to. its impossible to do it live for every visitor

Comment: It's not impossible unless the target site blocks your request if you do it too often, but it's really not needed to pull the data live unless you expect it to change by the minute. Cache or store it and use that result instead is much better for a lot of reasons

Comment: @Qirel I would love to see your code to compare a few hundreds sites on any random product in real time for multiple users.

Comment: I never said it was a good solution at all - like I said, storing it is much better for so many reasons. I just said it wasn't *impossible* to do it, but it's indeed really, really impractical. Which is what my other comment already said.